# How much memory I'll get If I'll run my code?

Tags: java, jvm

What size of memory I will get if I will run this code?

```
List<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
for (long i = 0; i < 4_000_000_000L; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
```

8Gb?

Comment: this question can't be answered precisely and there are some mistakes in it aswell. 1.: 8GB = 2^33 bytes, not 4 bn. 2.: an `int` is a word or 4 bytes long. 3.: there will aswell be some overhead due to the structure. 4.: the VM also produces some memory-overhead.

Comment: Long is 64 bit or 8 byte so 8 * 4000000000 bytes roughly

Comment: Yeah hypothetically. Obviously you'll crash long before that

Comment: I gave to my JVM 12Gb of memory (`-Xmx12g`). :) But if it eats 32G then it will be not enough anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such questions can be answered using the [Java Object Layout](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/) tool. Here's the test code:

```
import org.openjdk.jol.info.GraphLayout;

import org.openjdk.jol.util.VMSupport;
import java.util.*;

public class JOLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 4000L; i++) {
            list.add(i);
            if((i+1) % 1000 == 0) {
                System.out.println("i = "+(i+1));
                System.out.println(GraphLayout.parseInstance(list).toFootprint());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have not enough memory to check 4_000_000_000 entries, but it's not necessary as `LinkedList` memory allocation is linear:

```
i = 1000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      1000        24     24000   java.lang.Long
         1        32        32   java.util.LinkedList
      1000        24     24000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      2001               48032   (total)


i = 2000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      2000        24     48000   java.lang.Long
         1        32        32   java.util.LinkedList
      2000        24     48000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      4001               96032   (total)


i = 3000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      3000        24     72000   java.lang.Long
         1        32        32   java.util.LinkedList
      3000        24     72000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      6001              144032   (total)


i = 4000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      4000        24     96000   java.lang.Long
         1        32        32   java.util.LinkedList
      4000        24     96000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      8001              192032   (total)
```

So you practically have `(48*n+32)` bytes spent for `n` elements in the list, of which `24*n` is `Long` instance, `24*n` is internal `LinkedList$Node` instance and `32` is `LinkedList` itself. Thus the answer on your question would be `192_000_000_032 bytes`... But this test was performed for small (<32Gb) `-Xmx` value when [compressed oops](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) work. For bigger amounts the numbers are different:

```
$ java -Xmx32G -cp test-1.0.jar JOLTest
i = 1000

java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      1000        24     24000   java.lang.Long
         1        48        48   java.util.LinkedList
      1000        40     40000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      2001               64048   (total)


i = 2000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      2000        24     48000   java.lang.Long
         1        48        48   java.util.LinkedList
      2000        40     80000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      4001              128048   (total)


i = 3000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      3000        24     72000   java.lang.Long
         1        48        48   java.util.LinkedList
      3000        40    120000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      6001              192048   (total)


i = 4000
java.util.LinkedList@41a4555ed footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
      4000        24     96000   java.lang.Long
         1        48        48   java.util.LinkedList
      4000        40    160000   java.util.LinkedList$Node
      8001              256048   (total)
```

Thus in your case it's actually `(64*n+48)` bytes, namely `256_000_000_048` (roughly 256Gb).

Note that the results were obtained on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_40. It's not guaranteed that different JDK/JVM will produce the same result.

Also please note that normally Java collections cannot fit more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements as size is stored in `int`. Looking into `LinkedList` implementation you can see that (assuming that you have enough memory) you will get no exception, but the size will silently overflow, thus probably it would be hard to work with this collection after that.

Comment: Good one. I tried it with a list of Long and Byte, and putting 2 values in it. Then upon parsing the instance of both list, I get `java.util.LinkedList@347cdbd footprint:
     COUNT       AVG       SUM   DESCRIPTION
         2        16        32   java.lang.Long
         1        24        24   java.util.LinkedList
         2        24        48   java.util.LinkedList$Node
         5                 104   (total)` But I couldn't understand how. Why memory for Byte allocation was also 64 byte?

Comment: @hagrawal, seems that you tried on 32bit JVM, right? Note that Long/Byte/etc. are objects, not primitives, so you have to spent some space for object header (which has pointer to class, some bits to support synchronization, etc.). You should not worry about Bytes though: there are only 256 different values and they are cached (see `Byte.valueOf` implementation). So you will not have more than 256 Byte objects (assuming you don't call `new Byte()` explicitly).